# My Python webserver is being bombarded with malicious PHP requests. Should I do something?

Tags: nginx, abuse

My Python server (running Flask, uWSGI & NGinx) is currently receiving a ton of GET requests for what I assume are PHP hacks and exploits. Here's a few I've pulled from my logs:

```
"GET /dbadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /web/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /admin/pma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /admin/PMA/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /admin/mysql/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /admin/mysql2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /admin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /admin/phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /mysqladmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /mysql-admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpmyadmin0/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpmyadmin1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /myadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /myadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /xampp/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpMyadmin_bak/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /www/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /tools/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpmyadmin-old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpMyAdminold/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpMyAdmin.old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /pma-old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /claroline/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /typo3/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /phpma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I've done my best to secure my server against *relevant* dangers, but should I do anything about this? Or should I just let these people waste their time?

Comment: Is the python server a public one in the Internet, just for your use or for a small, restritcted subset of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty typical for any publicly-exposed web server. They're just probing for commonly known exploits (of which, php has many). If you're not vulnerable, then I would just ignore it. If you block them, someone else will just come along. If they're not causing problems for you, then just let them keep wasting their time.

Comment: Thank you. It seems logical that any challenge from me would simply provoke them further, so I'll leave leave them be.

Comment: Most of those attacks are automated...botnets.